# Get form select field values from view

Tags: views, forms

I'm struggling to find a working method for populating the key & value pairs of a select field (created with forms api) with data from a view.

e.g.. I have a view of 'location' content types.

In the form I've created I need a drop down showing all these location names and a reference from their content type as the key.

Can anyone suggest the easiest method?

Comment: why does it need to come from a View? why not retrieve the information directly from the db?

Comment: Good point - no good reason I suppose, would that be your preferred method?

Comment: since you're only retrieving very limited information, and providing the end user has no control over what information is retrieved, that's how I would do it... but that's just an opinion of course.  There's lots of resources on db retrieval to look at. Here's a some info on securely writing: https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code

Comment: I ended up using node_load_multiple as all the data needed was from the same content type. Seemed somewhat faster than querying directly - any disadvantages to this approach?

Comment: none that come to mind - it should take care of most of the retrieval security issues as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of using Views to handle the query, for performance reasons you are probably better off doing something more direct with the db, just make sure that you follow standards for security when accessing the db via any method. [Here](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code) is a link to the Writing Secure Code documentation - a must read for anyone delving into this area.